Is there any correlation between '401 (Unauthorized)' and 'deserializeuser not called'?"
http://localhost:3005/api/users/survey 401 (Unauthorized)
client -  "This code is for displaying a modal when the user hasn't completed the survey."
useEffect(() => {
    async function getSurvery() {
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3005/api/users/survey', {
            method: 'GET',
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${authInfo.token}`,
            },
        })

        if (response.status !== 200) {
            console.log('response is not ok')
            return
        }

        const data = await response.json()
        console.log(data)
        openModal()
    }

    getSurvery()
}, [authInfo.token, openModal])

server -

app.js

var createError = require('http-errors')
var express = require('express')
var path = require('path')
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
var logger = require('morgan')
var expressLayouts = require('express-ejs-layouts')
require('dotenv').config()
const cors = require('cors')
var session = require('express-session')

// swagger
const swaggerUi = require('swagger-ui-express')
const swaggerJsdoc = require('swagger-jsdoc')
const swaggerDefinition = require('./swagger/swaggerDef')

// passport
const passport = require('passport')
const passportConfig = require('./passport/index.js')

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index')
var usersAPIRouter = require('./routes/userAPI')
var commonAPIRouter = require('./routes/commonAPI')
var collegeAPIRouter = require('./routes/collegeAPI')
var sportsAPIRouter = require('./routes/sportsAPI')

var sequelize = require('./models/index.js').sequelize
var app = express()
sequelize.sync()

const corsOptions = {
    origin: 'http://localhost:5173',
    credentials: true,
}

app.use(cors(corsOptions))

// passport
passportConfig(passport)

app.use(
    session({
        resave: false,
        saveUninitialized: false,
        secret: process.env.COOKIE_SECRET,
        cookie: {
            httpOnly: true,
            secure: false,
            maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, // 1 day
        },
    }),
)

const options = {
    swaggerDefinition,
    apis: ['./routes/*.js', './swagger/*'],
}
const swaggerSpec = swaggerJsdoc(options)
app.use('/api-docs', swaggerUi.serve, swaggerUi.setup(swaggerSpec))

app.use(passport.initialize())
app.use(passport.session())

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

// app.set('layout', 'layout')

// app.set('layout extractScripts', true)
// app.set('layout extractStyles', true)
// app.set('layout extractMetas', true)
// app.use(expressLayouts)

app.use(logger('dev'))
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
app.use(cookieParser())
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')))

app.use('/', indexRouter)
app.use('/api/users', usersAPIRouter)
app.use('/api/common', commonAPIRouter)
app.use('/api/college', collegeAPIRouter)
app.use('/api/sports', sportsAPIRouter)
app.use('/public', express.static('public'))

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    next(createError(404))
})

// error handler
app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    // set locals, only providing error in development
    res.locals.message = err.message
    res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {}

    // render the error page
    res.status(err.status || 500)
    res.render('error')
})

module.exports = app

passport index.js 
const local = require('./localStrategy')
const kakao = require('./kakaoStrategy')
const admin = require('./adminStrategy')
const db = require('../models/index')

// serializeUser: pass user_id
// deserializeUser: find user by user_id and pass user data
// user data includes [user_id, email, name, nickname, profile_img, phone, birth_date]
module.exports = (passport) => {
    passport.serializeUser((userSessionData, done) => {
        const id = userSessionData.admin_id
            ? { type: 'admin', id: userSessionData.admin_id }
            : { type: 'user', id: userSessionData.user_id }
        console.log('serializeUser:', id)
        done(null, id)
    })

    passport.deserializeUser(async (userId, done) => {
        console.log('deserializeUser:', userId)
        try {
            if (userId.type === 'admin') {
                const admin = await db.Admins.findOne({
                    where: { admin_id: userId.id },
                    attributes: ['admin_id', 'id', 'name', 'email'],
                })
                done(null, admin)
                return
            }
            const user = await db.Users.findOne({
                where: { user_id: userId },
                attributes: ['user_id', 'email', 'name', 'nickname', 'profile_img', 'phone', 'birth_date'],
            })
            done(null, user)
        } catch (error) {
            console.error(error)
            done(error, null)
        }
    })

    local(passport)
    admin(passport)
    kakao(passport)
}


localStrategy.js

var bcrypt = require('bcryptjs')
const LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy
var db = require('../models/index')
const enums = require('../common/enums.js')
const { Op } = require('sequelize')

// passport-local
// if success, return userSessionData / if fail, return message
// userSessionData: { user_id, email, name, nickname, profile_img, phone, birth_date }
module.exports = (passport) => {
    passport.use(
        'user_local',
        new LocalStrategy(
            {
                usernameField: 'email',
                passwordField: 'password',
            },
            async (email, password, done) => {
                try {
                    const user = await db.Users.findOne({
                        where: {
                            email: email,
                            use_status_code: {
                                [Op.ne]: enums.USE_STATUS_CODE.WITHDRAWAL,
                            },
                        },
                    })
                    if (!user) {
                        return done(null, false, {
                            message: '존재하지 않는 사용자입니다.',
                        })
                    }
                    const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)
                    if (!isMatch) {
                        return done(null, false, {
                            message: '비밀번호가 일치하지 않습니다.',
                        })
                    }
                    var userSessionData = {
                        user_id: user.user_id,
                        is_user_verified: user.is_user_verified,
                        email: user.email,
                        name: user.name,
                        nickname: user.nickname,
                        profile_img: user.profile_img,
                        phone: user.phone,
                        birth_date: user.birth_date,
                    }
                    return done(null, userSessionData)
                } catch (error) {
                    console.error(error)
                    return done(error)
                }
            },
        ),
    )
}

"expecting:
Although we confirmed that the token is being passed correctly in the developer tools network, req.isAuthenticated() returns false on the backend.
Try:
Verified the use of req.login.
Checked CORS settings.
Confirmed the initialization of sessions and their placement."

Firstly you must to put the token which u get after auth in the localStorage. After in the useEffect function you must get this token

The token is currently stored in a cookie and is being fetched.
We'll update the code accordingly.

"I've resolved the issue. It turns out there was an error on the backend related to considering the administrator, which I hadn't taken into account. Thank you for your comments."

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
